# MATLAB - subs method doesn't work on symbolic vector of indexed variables

Tags: matlab, vector, substitution, symbolic-math

Consider the following code:

```
A = sym('a', [1, 2]);
b = sym('b');
ans = A.^2 + b;
A = [1, 2];
b = 4;
subs(ans)
```

This yields the output

> ans =   [ a1^2 + 4, a2^2 + 4]

Whereas I would have wanted it to produce

> ans =   [  5, 8]

What is required for the vector to be converted to numeric values aswell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simpler solution:

```
syms A b;        %Initializing symbolic variables
expr = A^2 + b;  %Your expression (element-wise square is taken by default for sym class) 

A = [1 2];   b=4;  %Assigning the values
subs(expr)         %Substituting symbolic variables with corresponding assigned values
```

Output as desired:

```
ans = 
[ 5, 8]
```

---

**Comments:**

1. Always avoid dynamic variables. In your code, you're specifying `A` to be `[1, 2]` but your expression doesn't actually have `A` in it. It has `a1` and `a2` (and `b` obviously).
2. Don't name your variables/functions after the reserved variable names or in-built functions. [**`ans`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ans.html) is used for the *Most Recent Answer when expressions are not assigned to anything else*. (That's why I replaced `ans` in your code with `expr`)